# SEO friendly routing in Play

Tags: url, seo, playframework, directory

Short version: Is there an attractive, simple way of implementing a language-specific url structure, ala. host.com/en/ or host.com/pt/ in Play 1.2.5?

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require changing all controllers, and the change should preferably only be to the routing file, as I don't want two sets of redundant views - one for each language.

I already have a message.pt and message.en, and I have a way of switching between the two, but I'm a newb when it comes to routing.

I realize that the routing file can contain a route like: "/(en|pt)/" but I'm kinda stuck here.

I appologies if the question is a bit vague.
I'll gladly clarify should the need arise.

Comment: Have you tried something similar to how the tutorial defines what task to render? Something along the lines of `POST    /tasks/:id/delete       controllers.Application.deleteTask(id: Long)`.

Comment: Dan: Wouldn't I have to change all controllers then?, to accept the lang attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in some old change notes for Play 1.1:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/releasenotes-1.1 (under "Global route arguments"). Odd that it isn't mentioned anywhere else.

[Edited to include the entire working solution]
[Edit2 - Fixed a problem]

My routes file look like this:

```
# Home page
GET     /{lang}/?                           Application.index
GET     /                                   Application.redirect
GET     /{lang}/woops/?                     Application.underConstruction
```

The language controller looks like this atm:

```
public class Language extends Controller {

@Before
static void detectLangInURL() {
    String url = request.url;

    if (url.length() > 2 && isSupported(getFromUrl(url)))
    {
        String lang = getFromUrl(url);
        if (!Lang.get().equals(lang)) {
            Lang.change(lang);
            response.setCookie("lang", lang, "60d");
        }
        renderArgs.put("lang", Lang.get());
        routeArgs.put("lang", Lang.get());
    }
}

private static String getFromUrl(String url) {
    String[] s = url.split("[/]");
    if (s.length > 1)
        return s[1];
    else return "";
}

private static boolean isSupported(String lang) {
    if (lang.length() == 0)
        return false;

    String[] langList = Play.configuration.get("application.langs").toString().split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < langList.length; i++) {
        if (langList[i].compareToIgnoreCase(lang) == 0)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

The redirect method looks like this:

```
public static void redirect() {
    Cookie lang = request.current().cookies.get("lang");
    if (lang != null && !lang.value.isEmpty())
        Lang.change(lang.value);
    redirect(Lang.get() + "/");
}
```

I had to choose between using a `@With(Language.class)` annotation or changing the Controller super class. I choose the @With annotation.

I'm pleased, it ended up being pretty simple.
I hope someone can benefit from the above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way around this, you will have to do something to your controllers.

I haven't tested this but something like this should work:

```
public static class LanguageParams extends Controller
{
    @Before
    static void addLanguageParam(String language)
    {
         renderArgs.put("lang", language);
    }
}
```

You will need to add @With to every controller like this:

```
@With(LanguageParams.class)
public class Foo extends Controller
{
....
}
```

... and in your route you would have something like this:

```
GET  foo/{<en|pt>language>}/whatever       Foo.index()
```

While writing this it came to my mind that you may be able to do this with a plugin, see: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2/play/PlayPlugin.html#beforeActionInvocation(java.lang.reflect.Method)